# Python module import error (Works fine in linux but fails in FreeBSD)

Tags: python, freebsd, python-module, python-import

We have an application which is currently working on a linux system. Now I am trying to port it to FreeBSD. We are running the application using **twistd**

```
/usr/bin/twistd -y $TACFILE --rundir $RUNDIR --logfile=/dev/null --pidfile=$PIDFILE
```

My tacfile is a python file which starts with these lines

```
#!/opt/python/bin/python

import os

from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
from twisted.plugin import getPlugins
from twisted.python import log

import labris.flyng.iflyng as iflyng
import labris.flyng.config as config
import labris.flyng.plugins as pplugins
import labris.flyng.protocols as flyng_protocols
```

But I get an error in this line:

```
import labris.flyng.iflyng as iflyng
```

The error is:

```
exceptions.ImportError: No module named labris.flyng.iflyng

Failed to load application: No module named labris.flyng.iflyng
```

But as you can understand twisted imports dont cause an error whereas labris imports fail. This application runs without any errors in linux.

And if it has something to do with it `/opt/python/bin/python` is a symbolic link pointing to `/usr/local/bin/python2.6`

Both twisted and labris directories are under the path
`/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages`
Their permissions are correct and each of them has the same permissions.

The output of `ls /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/labris/flyng` is 
`__init__.py    config.py   db      iflyng.py   parsers     plugins     protocols.py`
So I dont think there is an error with the module's path. I don't know what might be the cause of this error. Any clues, pointers is most welcome.

Comment: You can insert "assert False, sys.path" just before the line which causes the import error. Compare the results in both environments. Are they equal?

Comment: How did you installed these libraries on FreeBSD

Answer (score 0):

You might also try to import the module from a simple python script to see if it is installed in the right place